# Pandas: group one column by date and count cumulated number of a specific value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to group a Pandas dataframe by date based on one datetime column and, based on that, count the number of specific occurrences in another column based on a specific value. Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "customer": [
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"        
    ],
    "datetime": pd.to_datetime([
        "2020-01-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-02 00:00:00", "2020-01-02 01:00:00", "2020-01-03 00:00:00", "2020-01-04 00:00:00", "2020-01-03 00:00:00", "2020-01-03 00:00:00", "2020-01-04 00:00:00"         
    ]),
    "enabled": [
      True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True            
    ]    
})
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
customer    datetime                enabled
A           2020-01-01 00:00:00     True
A           2020-01-02 00:00:00     True
A           2020-01-02 01:00:00     False
A           2020-01-03 00:00:00     True
A           2020-01-04 00:00:00     True
B           2020-01-03 00:00:00     True
C           2020-01-03 00:00:00     False
C           2020-01-04 00:00:00     True
```

I would like to count, at the end of each day, the number of enabled customers. If a customer is enabled, it remains enabled for the following days, unless there's an `enabled==False` row on a later day. The expected output would be:

```
day           count_enabled_customers
2020-01-01    1      # A
2020-01-02    0      # A has been disabled
2020-01-03    2      # A, B
2020-01-04    3      # A, B, C
```

Does someone have an idea of how to proceed with this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For day ``2020-01-04`` the count shouldn't be 2 (A,C) ?

Comment: @Sushanth customer B was enabled on '2020-01-03' and not disabled after that, so (s)he remains enabled on the following days, if that makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "customer": [
         "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"        
    ],
    "datetime": pd.to_datetime([
        "2020-01-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-02 00:00:00", "2020-01-02 01:00:00", "2020-01-03 00:00:00", "2020-01-04 00:00:00", "2020-01-03 00:00:00", "2020-01-03 00:00:00", "2020-01-04 00:00:00"         
    ]),
    "enabled": [
      True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True            
    ]    
})

print(df)

Out:
  customer            datetime  enabled
0        A 2020-01-01 00:00:00     True
1        A 2020-01-02 00:00:00     True
2        A 2020-01-02 01:00:00    False
3        A 2020-01-03 00:00:00     True
4        A 2020-01-04 00:00:00     True
5        B 2020-01-03 00:00:00     True
6        C 2020-01-03 00:00:00    False
7        C 2020-01-04 00:00:00     True
```

Use a pivot to get the customers as columns and the dates as an index

```
a = df.pivot(index='datetime', columns='customer', values='enabled')
print(a)

Out:
customer                 A     B      C
datetime                               
2020-01-01 00:00:00   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 00:00:00   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 01:00:00  False   NaN    NaN
2020-01-03 00:00:00   True  True  False
2020-01-04 00:00:00   True   NaN   True
```

Create an index of the dates you are interested in

```
dates = pd.date_range(df.datetime.min().date(), df.datetime.max().date() + pd.offsets.Day(1), freq='D') - pd.offsets.Second(1)
print(dates)

Out:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-31 23:59:59', '2020-01-01 23:59:59',
               '2020-01-02 23:59:59', '2020-01-03 23:59:59',
               '2020-01-04 23:59:59'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Add the dates you are interested in to the index and sort it so we can ffill in the next step

```
a = a.reindex(a.index.union(dates)).sort_index()
print(a)

Out:
customer                 A     B      C
2019-12-31 23:59:59    NaN   NaN    NaN
2020-01-01 00:00:00   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-01 23:59:59    NaN   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 00:00:00   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 01:00:00  False   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 23:59:59    NaN   NaN    NaN
2020-01-03 00:00:00   True  True  False
2020-01-03 23:59:59    NaN   NaN    NaN
2020-01-04 00:00:00   True   NaN   True
2020-01-04 23:59:59    NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Forward fill the last value of the enabled state into future dates

```
a = a.ffill()
print(a)

Out: 
customer                 A     B      C
2019-12-31 23:59:59    NaN   NaN    NaN
2020-01-01 00:00:00   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-01 23:59:59   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 00:00:00   True   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 01:00:00  False   NaN    NaN
2020-01-02 23:59:59  False   NaN    NaN
2020-01-03 00:00:00   True  True  False
2020-01-03 23:59:59   True  True  False
2020-01-04 00:00:00   True  True   True
2020-01-04 23:59:59   True  True   True
```

Sum across columns for the timestamps which represent the ends of each day

```
a.loc[dates].sum(axis=1)
print(a)

Out:
2019-12-31 23:59:59    0.0
2020-01-01 23:59:59    1.0
2020-01-02 23:59:59    0.0
2020-01-03 23:59:59    2.0
2020-01-04 23:59:59    3.0
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @davidfdez @jamesschofield  `df.set_index(['datetime', 'customer'])['enabled'].unstack().ffill().resample('D').last().sum(axis=1)`  All in one line.

Comment: @ScottBoston, an improved answer overall i think. Though I would still keep the pivot as it makes the code more explicit than `df.set_index(['datetime', 'customer'])['enabled'].unstack()` imo

Comment: Actually the pivot doesn't work well with the resample so i would say this is the best answer. Upvoted

Comment: Combining both proposals, one can also do: ```df.pivot_table(index='datetime', columns='customer', values="enabled").ffill().resample('D').last().sum(axis=1)```. Both ideas are awesome, thanks folks!